# search for a public key on a keyserver with GPGME

Tags: c, gnupg, gpgme

Today I started a new thread on gnupg mailing list, [Search keys on a keyserver with GPGME](http://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-devel/2012-December/027183.html). Basically I use GPGME as an interface to use GnuPG in my app, but I don't know how I can use GPGME functions to search for a key on a keyserver.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer for this problem.
Using **gpgme_op_conf_load**, **gpgme_conf_arg_new**, **gpgme_conf_opt_change** and **gpgme_op_conf_save** it is possible to set a new preference, in this case the keyserver url.

--
Cheer,
José

Comment: FFR: These options are undocumented but exemplified in [`./tests/gpg/t-gpgconf.c`](http://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gpgme.git;a=blob;f=tests/gpg/t-gpgconf.c)