# Importing key from server with gpgme

Tags: gnupg, gpgme

I'm trying to import a key from a keyserver using GPGME. I'm sure the key exists, since I can see it when I access the server with my browser. I followed the manual and produced this:

```
gpgme_key_t key;
gpgme_keylist_mode_t mode = gpgme_get_keylist_mode(ctx);
mode &= ~GPGME_KEYLIST_MODE_LOCAL;
mode |= GPGME_KEYLIST_MODE_EXTERN;

err = gpgme_set_keylist_mode(ctx, mode);    
err = gpgme_get_key(ctx, id, &key, 0);
```

The keyring directory is configured at the beginning:

```
gpgme_set_engine_info(GPGME_PROTOCOL_OpenPGP, NULL, KeyringDir);
```

That directory contains a gpg.conf file with a "keyserver" entry specifiying the URL of the server. The global gpg.conf has the same directive with the same URL too.

The issue is that the import fails with the error "End of file", which means "not found". The id I pass has 8 characters starting with 0x, since I heard there may be issues with different formats.
Browing this site I found this related question [search for a public key on a keyserver with GPGME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870240/search-for-a-public-key-on-a-keyserver-with-gpgme/13921186#13921186) however I'm not sure how those functions are supposed to be used, and they don't appear in the manual.

Thanks for the help.